# pandas.Series.dt.round inconsistent behaviour on NAT's with different freq arguments?

Tags: python, pandas

I found an inconsistent behaviour in `pandas.Series.dt.round`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
d=pd.DataFrame(data=[[datetime(2010,1,1,23,14,12,599), 2], [None, 4]], columns=['dtime', 'int'])

print d['dtime'].dt.round('s')
0   2010-01-01 23:14:12
1                   NaT
Name: dtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print d['dtime'].dt.round('5s')
0   2010-01-01 23:14:10.000000000
1   2262-04-10 00:12:44.999999488  # what?
Name: dtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print d['dtime'].dt.round('min')
0   2010-01-01 23:14:00
1   2262-04-10 00:13:00  # again???
Name: dtime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So, in the first case (freq argument 's') NaT are preserved (I would say, as I expect). However, in the second and third case, NaT's are converted to some apparently weird date time.
Let alone alternative solutions, does somebody knows more about this (seemingly) bug? or do I miss some (hidden) feature, or some (even more hidden) link where the topic is discussed?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, the `NaT` value should be preserved here irrespective of the `round` frequency, actually you've already posted an [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14940)